# Allow internal users to edit partner users' calendar events that they (internal) created

Tags: community, partner

We have internal users that create calendar events for our partner users. When they do that, they assign the event to the partner user. Apparently, one of my internal users claim that she used to be able to edit the event after creation and saving but that has stopped working. The internal users' profile allows "Edit Events."

Do you know how I can grant any extra permissions for my internal users to be able to edit the calendar events for partner users?

Our activity sharing is set to Private and calendar is full share with details. The private activity sharing doesn't concern me as much since the user said she's been able to edit before.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out those internal users just needed to be Account Owners for the account records those events are tied to.